# How can I modify Firebase Storage Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm storing images under uid/PropertyPhotos/Property# (where # is incremented as images are uploaded). The uid belongs to the user that posted the image, not the current logged on Firebase user. What I'd like is to allow anyone to view those images. How do I modify the storage rule below to allow that?

```
    service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    // we want anyone to view the property images (no auth, publicy readable)
    match /{uid}/PropertyPhotos {
        allow read;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should instead organize all those files under a dedicated path, and protect everything under that one path.  Starting the path with the uid makes this much harder to manage.

Comment: But I need to link those images to the owner that posted them. Are you suggesting some path like PropertyPhotos/uid/Property# ?